# Strange sytax error with nested keyword parameters

Tags: python, nested, python-multiprocessing, scapy, sniffing

I am currently trying to code some sort of QoS box by utilizing MITM via ARP poisioning.
Now I ran into a syntax error I can not seem to resolve:

```
File "/home/pi/qosmitm/networker.py", line 53
self.recv_threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=sniff, args=(iface=interface,
                                                                          ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The Code:

```
    for i in range(0, len(net_map[0])):
            ip = net_map[0][i]
            mac = net_map[1][i]
            self.packet_queues.append(multiprocessing.Queue())
            self.recv_threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=sniff, args=(iface=interface, filter='host ' + ip, prn=mitm.recv_packets(self.packet_queues[i]))))
```

interface is a string.

And here is the recv_packets funktion:

```
def recv_packets(self, queue): # not too sure bout that
    def recv_packets(self, pkt):
        # flip macs & put into queue
        old_src = pkt[Ether].src
        print(pkt.summary())
        pkt[Ether].src = pkt[Ether].dst
        pkt[Ether].dst = old_src                                                                          queue.put(pkt)
```

I checked the different docs but I could not find out what I am doing wrong. My guess is that it is somehow related to the nested function calls/callbacks(?).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `args` parameter to `multiprocessing.Process` is for positional parameters only.  To specify keyword arguments, you pass them as `kwargs`, in the form of a dictionary.

Comment: thanks, that did it! that is why you should learn the basics of a programming language first, i see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @jasonharper for clearifying this. Read his comment below my question for an explanation to this corrected code snipped.

```
self.recv_threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=sniff, args={'iface':interface, filter':'host ' + ip, 'prn':mitm.recv_packets(self.packet_queues[i])})
```

Go drop him an upvote for the quick answer. Much appreciated!